# Cross-platform code-signing of .tar.gz file using OpenSSL?

Tags: security, openssl, code-signing

I'm adding automatic upgrades to an application of mine.  I need code-signing for this, or else automatic upgrades could be an attack vector.  I need the signing and verification to be doable with "openssl" commands, since my application can run on any platform, and OpenSSL is available on any platform.  However, when I try to verify a timestamp with openssl, with the code-signing certificate I bought from Comodo, I get the error "Verify error:unable to get local issuer certificate".  The commands I run are as follows:

First, I extract the private key and the certificates from the .p12 file from Comodo, with the following:

```
openssl pkcs12 -in full-certs-from-comodo.p12 -nocerts -out private-key.pem
openssl pkcs12 -in full-certs-from-comodo.p12 -nokeys -out certs.pem
```

Then, to query and verify a timestamp, I run:

```
openssl ts -query -data mydata.tar.gz -cert -CAfile certs.pem -sha256 -out request-256.tsq
cat request-256.tsq | curl -s -S --data-binary @- -H 'Content-Type: application/timestamp-query' 'http://timestamp.comodoca.com?td=sha256' > response-256.tsr
openssl ts -verify -sha256 -in response-256.tsr -data mydata.tar.gz -CAfile certs.pem
```

This is the full error that results:

```
Verification: FAILED
140710242829968:error:2F06D064:time stamp routines:TS_VERIFY_CERT:certificate verify error:ts_rsp_verify.c:246:Verify error:unable to get local issuer certificate
```

Comodo tech support can't solve it, and I've been communicating with them for a month now.  Digicert says they can only sign certain kinds of files, and those don't include a .tar.gz file.  `*sigh*`

I've never used code-signing before, but that doesn't sound right to me, unless Digicert is adding artificial restrictions.  Can't I hash any file, sign the hash with a private key, and then verify it on the user end with the public key?  I don't think it should be this hard.  What don't I understand?

Anyway, I'd love to get this working even with a paid certificate vendor, but failing that I'm wondering if I can just create my own key pair (a la PGP) and use that.  I guess I wouldn't be able to revoke the certificate; are there any other downsides?  In particular, does anyone see any reduced security by doing it this way?  I do need very good security for this app.

The application is a Perl script and normally runs on a Web server, i.e. usually a *nix platform, but can also run on Windows.

Thanks!  I appreciate any clues in getting this working at all, in any way, paid or not.  I can't be the first person to need this kind of code-signing, but Comodo and Digicert tech support seemingly haven't heard of it at all.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe not an answer but definitely too much for comments.

Aside: OpenSSL is available on many platforms, but not all. Although you only care about platforms where your app can be installed, and perl is already pretty demanding of platforms and can't be installed anywhere near everywhere.

More Important: code-signing and trusted timestamping are different and separate things, although sometimes used together: some codesigning schemes like Microsoft and Java encourage (but don't require) you to get a trusted timestamp on the (code) signature; I'm not sure about Apple, or Android. In particular you can't (validly) use a code-signing cert for timestamping, or verifying timestamps, and if you can get a timestamping cert (you probably can't meet the requirements to be trusted by anyone besides yourself, see below) you can't use it for signing or verifying code. Although the error you got on `ts` is probably not because of this misuse but because you did something else wrong, but you don't tell us what you did, and imagining and describing the very many things you could possibly have done wrong would take far more than is justified for or even fits in a single Stack answer.

The cert can't restrict what you can sign, but it may restrict where that signature will be trusted. In particular for Microsoft Authenticode, only a cert from a CA specifically approved by Microsoft will work. And I believe Apple only trusts certs they themselves issue.

**Yes, if you control both/all ends you don't need a 'real' cert**; the (only) value of a trusted-thirdparty CA, and certs from it, is allowing your system(s) and/or code to trust data or code from those of other people, and/or other people's to trust yours, under known and more or less reasonable conditions. You presumably trust yourself entirely, unless you're [Michael Garibaldi](https://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/Babylon_5#Matters_of_Honor). If you use OpenSSL's 'primitive' signing functions (commandline `dgst -sign/verify` or `rsautl/pkeyutl -sign/verify`, or the equivalent library calls) you only need the two keys, private and public. If you use CMS (aka PKCS7) or S/MIME signatures you need *a* cert, but it can be a self-signed cert with any identity information, true or false, you feel like putting in it.

Comment: Ah, sorry for the omission-- I just edited the original post to include the openssl commands I ran.

Interesting that I need different certs for code-signing and timestamping; I didn't realize that.  I need to do both.